# Reusing a component with slightly different Inputs

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a card component I'd like to reuse to render data, but the `@Input()`s are slightly different objects (articles vs events).

**Parent HTML:**

```
<card-component [headline]="Articles"
                [content]="articles">
</card-component>

<card-component [headline]="Events"
                [content]="events">
</card-component>
```

**Card Component TS:**

```
@Input() headline!: string;
@Input() content!: Array<Article> | Array<Event>
```

**Article object:**

```
{
  author: string,
  blurb: string
}
```

**Event object:**

```
{
  organizer: string,
  location: string,
  rsvpRequired: boolean
}
```

My assumption is that in the `card component ts` I need to make a simple object that would normalize `Article` and `Events` into an either an single type, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution may provide some clue, which is to have optional inputs

TS:

```
@Input() headline!: string;
@Input() articles?: Array<Article>
@Input() events?: Array<Event>
```

by doing so, pass necessary inputs wherever you use, if the content is of articles pass [articles]="articles" alone, vice versa.